# How to forpass Invisible reCAPTCHA badge

Tags: python, selenium, automation, captcha

How to overcome the invisible reCAPTCHA badge. I am trying to automate a site by sending userid and password but I get an Invalid captcha error where as I don't actually enter any captcha as it's invisible.

I did find the following:

`reCAPTCHA v2 - Invisible reCAPTCHA badge: The invisible reCAPTCHA badge does not require the user to click on a checkbox, instead it is invoked directly when the user clicks on an existing button on your site or can be invoked via a JavaScript API call. The integration requires a JavaScript callback when reCAPTCHA verification is complete. By default only the most suspicious traffic will be prompted to solve a captcha. To alter this behavior edit your site security preference under advanced settings.`

But I am unable to figure out what changes are to be made.
Can anyone please guide me through this?

Comment: as always please provide your code and what you tried for recaptcha in general you should ask the devs to desactivate it for you other than that the other solutions are realy complicated

Comment: @Yan There is this invisible recaptcha at the bottom right end of the site, so when the login credentials are entered after the click on the button it gives invalid captcha error message  on the login form.